# CreateThread doesn't work in my code

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I wonder how to solve this problem.

I notice that `CreateThread()` doesn't work well in this code:

```
DWORD threadFunc1(LPVOID lParam)
{
   int cur = (int)lParam
   while(1)
   {
       //Job1...

       //Reason     
             break;
   }
   Start(cur + 1);
   Sleep(100);
}

void Start(int startNum)
{
    ....
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFunc1, &startNum, 0, &dwThreadId);
    ...
}

void  btnClicking()
{
    Start(0);
}
```

In this code, there is a thread create by `Start()` and it calls `Start()` when the thread ends.

The second created thread does not work. I think the first thread disappeared and the second thread is destroyed.

What is the best way to solve this?

OS:   Win 7 64bit Ultimate.
Tool: Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: In a program that uses MFC, you should use [`afxBeginThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) instead of `CreateThread`.

Comment: Um, you are passing a pointer to a local variable, and then casting it to an integer in the thread procedure. This tends to create confusion. (Also: Your thread procedure is incorrectly declared. Remove the `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)` cast to see what's wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your code has bugs in it.  The signature of your thread function is wrong, and you are passing the startNum value to the thread in the wrong way.

Try this instead:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadFunc1(LPVOID lParameter)
{
   int cur = (int) lParameter;

   while(1)
   {
       //Job1...

       //Reason     
             break;
   }

   Start(cur + 1);
   Sleep(100);
}

void Start(int startNum)
{
    ....
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &threadFunc1, (LPVOID) startNum, 0, &dwThreadId);
    if (hThread != NULL)
    {
        // ... store it somewhere or close it, otherwise you are leaking it...
    }
    ...
}

void  btnClicking()
{
    Start(0);
}
```

Comment: Is leaking is the cause? But in end of thread func it maybe terminate it self I think.

Comment: I think passing startNum func is a fault, but this isn't main fault in this question.  I wanna know more clearly why second thread doesn't work. thanks

Comment: What "doesn't work" for you exactly? You need to be more specific. Does `CreateThread()` return a NULL handle? Does `threadFunc1()` not get called? Or is the real problem occurring inside the thread code that you have not shown yet? As for a thread terminating, you still have to close your open handle to it when you are done using it in order to release its resources.

Comment: doesn't work means-- success in CreateThread() but second disappeard in end of first thread. And this project is private so I can't release it. sorry

Comment: "second disappeard in end of first thread" - that is not very helpful. What "disappeard" exactly? As it stands, your provided code is not compilable and your problem is not reproducible. If you cannot provide your real code, then please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the same problem.